# Min timestamp to count how many articles per store_id

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count on an article_id level how many articles arrived in either `store_A` or `store_B` first by using the `arrival_timestamp`

See examples below:

Main table

```
arrival_timestamp           article_id   store_id

2019-04-01 11:04             2            A
2019-04-01 13:12             2            B
2019-04-01 08:24             4            A
2019-04-01 10:24             4            B
2019-04-10 07:00             7            A
2019-04-10 10:14             7            B
2019-04-23 07:34             9            A
2019-04-23 05:52             9            B
```

Output table

```
storeA_count_first_articles     storeB_count_first_articles
3                                1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
first_arrivals = df.assign(first_arrival_timestamp = df.groupby("article_id")["arrival_timestamp"].transform("min")).\
   query("arrival_timestamp == first_arrival_timestamp")
pd.pivot_table(first_arrivals, columns="store_id", aggfunc="count", values=["article_id"])
```

Output:

```
store_id    A  B
article_id  3  1
```